# setting up a cookie less sub domain

Tags: subdomain, cdn, cookieless, cloudflare

previously I served images for my site (http://example.com) from these two folders : http://example.com/images and http://example.com/pics

Now I have created a sub domain img.examole.com and moved those folders to http://img.example.com/pics and http://img.example.com/images locations. I have also blocked access to http://example.com/img folder by editing .htaccess file so that the sub-domain can not be accessed as a directory of main site. It only can be accessed as http://img.example.com

How can I make this http://img.example.com subdomain a cookie less sub-domain?  Or can I add this http://img.example.com sub-domain to cloudflare? I do not want to add the main domain http://example.com to cloud flare. When I am trying to add http://example.com to cloud flare from my CPanel it is showing :

A type records cannot be directly routed though the CloudFlare network. Instead, click here and either switch the type of img.example.com. to CNAME

I have changed the image location to http://img.example.com/pics in all my articles. How to fix this? plz help..

Comment: what specifically do you want to fix? there are a lot of open questions on your 'question'.. is it how to use cloudflare for your site? or how to create the .htaccess file for your img subdomain?

Answer (score 4):

Being cookie-less and served by CDN are unrelated properties of a domain.

To make some domain cookie-less for your site you simply should not set cookies visible on that domain and make sure any other third party code you use on your site does not do so.

It is generally inconvinient to avoid cookies from example.com to not not be visible on sub-domains (often sites are served from 2 locations www.example.com and example.com). If you are fine to having cookies on just example.com  - make sure that all set-cookie headers specify exact domain ("example.com" not ".example.com") so cookies will not be visible on any subdomain. Another option is to move main site to subdomain and set cookies there (i.e. www.example.com), than again cookies will not "leak" to sibling sub-domains (i.e. "img.example.com")

It may be better idea to host static content on totally separate domain name - easier to controll cookies and potentially more posibilities for CDN (i.e. in some cases HTTPS traffic from CDN may require different actions for custom and CDN-provided domain).

Comment: hi, there is no 'COOKIE_DOMAIN' entry in my wp-config.php file

Comment: @AnikChakraborty, I did not realized that you have some php specfic question... Unfortunately I have no idea how cookies are configured in php.

Answer (score 2):

The browser will look at example.com and www.example.com differently. If you set cookies on example.com then it will look for them on requests to www.example.com and cookie-free.example.com which I expect is why you're having trouble getting a cookie free subdomain (because the top level has cookies).
Best practice is to use www.example.com as your site, and set cookies there, then if you use cookie-free.example.com (another subdomain, like www) it will not have the cookies which are looked for top down by browsers.

See http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said there's two distinct (but related) questions here:

1. Configuring server/application to serve assets from a cookieless sub-domain
2. Utilize CloudFlare for delivery of static assets.

For question #1, you'll need to ensure you're not assigning cookies to the entire domain (this is why the use of www. is recommended). There's good information on how to do this here:
[Serving Static Content from a Cookieless Domain](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/) and here: [4 Steps To Serve Static Content From Cookieless Subdomain](http://reginaldchan.net/serving-static-content-from-cookieless-subdomain/) - both of these article address your WordPress question with regard to 'COOKIKE_DOMAIN' setting as well.

Essentially, you'll need to ensure applications like Google Analytics and WordPress don't set cookies at a domain level, but rather restrict them to the www sub-domain.

For question #2, CloudFlare themselves state that they assign cookies to every static request:

> CloudFlare will add a security cookie to any domain or subdomain that is being proxied by our service. In addition, since CloudFlare is already caching your static content by default, there really is no need to have a cookieless domain.

[KB - Can I serve a cookieless domain or subdomain through CloudFlare?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169816-Can-I-serve-a-cookieless-domain-or-subdomain-through-CloudFlare-)